# column comprehension robust to missing values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have only been able to create a two column data frame from a defaultdict (termed `output`):

```
df_mydata = pd.DataFrame([(k, v) for k, v in output.items()], 
                   columns=['id', 'value'])
```

What I would like to be able to do is using this basic format also initiate the dataframe with three columns: 'id', 'id2' and 'value'. I have a separate defined dict that contains the necessary look up info, called `id_lookup`.

So I tried:

```
df_mydata = pd.DataFrame([(k, id_lookup[k], v) for k, v in output.items()], 
                   columns=['id', 'id2','value'])
```

I think I'm doing it right, but I get key errors. I will only know if `id_lookup` is exhaustive for all possible encounters in hindsight. For my purposes, simply putting it all together and placing 'N/A` or something for those types of errors will be acceptable.

Would the above be appropriate for calculating a new column of data using a defaultdict and a simple lookup dict, and how might I make it robust to key errors?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'value': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

id_lookup = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}

new_column = defaultdict(str)

# Loop through the df and populate the defaultdict
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        new_column[index] = id_lookup[row['id']]
    except KeyError:
        new_column[index] = 'N/A'

# Convert the defaultdict to a Series and add it as a new column in the df
df['id2'] = pd.Series(new_column)

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
   id  value  id2
0   1     10    A
1   2     20    B
2   3     30    C
3   4     40  N/A
​
```